# How to automatically connect to Wifi on boot for Pi2?

Tags: networking, wifi, pi-2

I am using a Pi2 with Wifi USB Wifi Adapter. Every time I boot, I have to connect to the wifi manually by providing the password. Is there any way Pi2 can automatically connect to the wifi on boot?

When I boot up, only Wifi Dongle is connected, not the ethernet cable.

My settings are as follows.

**/etc/network/interfaces**

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.40.201
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.40.0
broadcast 192.168.40.255
gateway 192.168.40.1
dns-nameservers 4.2.2.2

auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
iface default inet dhcp

auto wlan1
allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet manual
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

**/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf**

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
ssid="Cisco09589"
psk="password"
key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}
```

OS and Kernel version

**pi@raspberrypi ~ $ cat /proc/version**
Linux version 4.1.19-v7+ (dc4@dc4-XPS13-9333) (gcc version 4.9.3 (crosstool-NG crosstool-ng-1.22.0-88-g8460611) ) #858 SMP Tue Mar 15 15:56:00 GMT 2016

**pi@raspberrypi ~ $ lsb_release -a**
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Raspbian
Description: Raspbian GNU/Linux 8.0 (jessie)
Release: 8.0
Codename: jessie

**pi@raspberrypi ~ $ cat /etc/os-release**
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="8"
VERSION="8 (jessie)"
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"

Comment: Unless you are using a year old Raspbian this won't work. See [How do I set up networking/WiFi/Static IP](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697) If you still have problems you need to describe your network.

Comment: I tried that, However it's still not working. I have added the OS and kernel information in the question.

Comment: But what is the configuration of your network?

Comment: It's a wifi network with given settings. It's DHCP type.

Comment: please show your "iwconfig" after boot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue when I once configured the wifi through the preinstalled GUI. There was no other chance than reinstall raspian and make the whole configuration with `/etc/network/interfaces`.

I would recommend not using the `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` but instead put your wifi password and name into your configuration directly.

This would be my configuration with a static IP address to easily connect with your PI via ssh:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
    address 192.168.0.198
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.0.1
    broadcast 192.168.1.255
    gateway 192.168.0.1
    wpa-ssid "WIFINAME"
    wpa-psk "WIFIPASSWD"
```

Don't forget to restart your wifi, after you made your changes!

Answer (score 2):

Your current wlan0 configuration requires manual IP setup (like for eth0 in this file or via ifconfig like command). I hope you are using DHCP, so replace string "iface wlan0 inet manual" with "iface wlan0 inet dhcp".

Answer (score 2):

*I tried half a dozen tutorials using `wpa-supplicant`, `iw` and `/etc/network/interfaces`.
But they all did not work for me. Probably because they did not describe at all what they were doing. So I always ran into a point where it did not work and there was no error message nor any way to find out the source of the problem.*

Finally I simply tried installing the default network-manager. Which happens to be the gnome-network-manager but without any GUI part.

So in short, the solution is:

```
sudo apt --no-install-recommends install network-manager
nmcli connection add ifname wlan0 type wifi ssid <Your-SSID>
nmcli connection edit wifi-wlan0
```

While editing the config file you have to set WPA-PSK and the plain text password:

```
nmcli> goto wifi
nmcli 802-11-wireless> set mode infrastructure 
nmcli 802-11-wireless> back 
nmcli> goto wifi-sec 
nmcli 802-11-wireless-security> set key-mgmt wpa-psk 
nmcli 802-11-wireless-security> set psk <your-plain-text-password>
nmcli 802-11-wireless-security> save 
nmcli 802-11-wireless-security> quit
```

After that reboot and enjoy! The network-manager will take care of everything!

If it complains about permission, the recommended way seems to be to modify/overwrite the policykit rules from
`/usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.policy`. I gave up on that and used `sudo` instead. *If anybody knows a clean way to do it, tell us please!*

Here is a very good guide, but it's in german: https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/NetworkManager/NetworkManager_ohne_GUI/

Comment: this is the only working solution for me, thanks